# Why wont this command work in minecraft pe 1.1

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

Why wont this command work

```
/execute @e[type=arrow.skeleton] ~ ~ ~ tp @p @e[type=arrow.skeleton]
```

It's in a repeating command block

Answer (score 1):

This is because the entity name in the selector (@e/p/r/a) is wrong. There is no arrow.skeleton, just arrow.

Apart from that, this command can be simplified by taking away the entire execute portion. I'd also recommend entering a range. You can even use execute to move the range to the player, and the commandblock should be in the world spawn.

Command without anything:

```
/tp @p @e[type=arrow]
```

Command with range

```
/tp @p @e[type=arrow,r=100]
```

Command with relative range:

```
/execute @p ~ ~ ~ /tp @p @e[type=arrow,r=100]
```

To set the world spawn to the place where the command block is (to make sure it's always running also when you walk far away from it:

```
/setworldspawn
```

<-- Greetings -->